# select query inside in select query php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php    
$query = "select * from comments t1 
          inner join users t2 on t1.user_id = t2.UserId 
          where usercomplain_id='$id'";
$run =mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))
{
    $commentid = $row['comment_id'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $username = $row['UserName'];
    $userid1 = $row['UserId'];
    $date = $row['CDate'];
    $ageDate = time_elapsed_string($date);

?>

<div class="jumbotron" style="border:3px solid #2FAB9B; background-color:#68C8C6;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">

        <?php echo $comment; ?>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">

        <?php echo $ageDate; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <label>Comment by &nbsp;<a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $userid1; ?>"><?php echo $username; ?></a></span></label><br>
    <h5><b>Reply on this post</b></h5>

    <?php
    $query = "select * from Reply";
    $run = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
    ?>

    <a class="reply" data-role="<?php echo $commentid; ?>">Reply</a>

    <br>
    <br>

    <div style="width:63%; display:none;" class="replyForm" data-role="<?php echo $commentid; ?>">  
        <form method="post">
            <textarea name="comment[<?php echo $commentid; ?>]"  cols="100" rows="4"></textarea><br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="reply" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right" value="reply">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
```

It is a simple comment system in which **after each comment I want to display replies on that particular comment** using select inside a select query is returning only first record is there is any method to display those reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second query, which in inside the while loop, is over writing the result set of the first as both use the handle `$run`

This one

```
<?php
    $query = "select * from Reply";
    $run = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
?>
```

> Not quite sure if you even use the result of this query actually

But if you do change `$run` to say... `$run1` and at least it will not destroy `$run` while still inside the while loop that is using `$run`.